# How to create onPageLoad box so that a user can click an image which open a link in new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP.NET website and it's needed when user loads site homepage, a box pops up on page load (not a popup) with an image appear. When user clicks the image, it opens a link in a new tab?

I guess jQuery can do this or AJAX. I'm a noob in this! Hope you provide me with a sample functional code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. The code below creates an image on document ready and binds a click event to it which when clicked, will open a new tab.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var image = $('<img></img>').attr('id', 'my_image').attr('src', '/path/to/your/image.png')
   $('#container').append(image);

   $('#my_image').click(function(){ 
     var window = window.open('http://your_url/', '_blank');
     window.focus();
   });

});
</script>
```